# How to open implementation code in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using latest version of Intellij. I want to see implementation of code but it showing me compiled code. I don't understand what is wrong in here.

**Example Code**

```
private fun simpleWindowed(unFilteredMovieList: List<NewMovieItem>) {
    val numberList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    numberList.windowed(size = 2, step = 1, partialWindows = true).forEach { window: List<Int> ->
            val first = window.first()
            val second = window.last()
            println(window)
        }
}
```

**Intellij**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.9011.34, built on May 16, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+10-b829.9 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.nativeDebug (231.8770.15)

Kotlin: 231-1.8.21-IJ9011.34
```

You can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/TP5gPYoO_bY) when I tried to open the code it opens the compiled code.

Comment: How are you pulling the kotlin dependency. Seems like your build system isn't pulling the kotlin std lib source files.

Comment: @Casper thanks for reply. What do you mean by pulling the kotlin dependency..

Comment: Assuming you are using gradle, how does your gradle build config look like. You should have something like `plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10"
}` if you are using the kotlin dsl or if u are using groove it would be  `plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.10'
}`

Comment: Sorry I don't have gradle project in this one..

Comment: Well that might be the reason then. How did you setup your kotlin project.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try now gradle project..

Comment: Yeah In gradle project I can see the implementation of code.